# Run go test for specific package

Tags: go

I used the following command to run test for specific package

`go test fts -run run_test.go`

> can't load package: package fts: cannot find package "fts" in any of:/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.11.1/libexec/src/integration (from $GOROOT)/Users/i055555/go/src/fts (from $GOPATH)

And the package looks like

```
gitproj/
    |---- fts
      |---- -command
        |---- -run.go
         |---- -run_test.go
    |---- internal
        |---- -fs.go
           |---- -tb.go
           |---- -tb_test.go
    main.go
```

Comment: If it is not in your GOPATH, try running it using relative path e.g. `go test ./fts/command`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So you can run `go test` for a specific package by giving it the relative path:

```
go test ./fts/command
```

The `--run` flag takes a regular expression that helps dictates which tests will be ran within the package.

For example if you had a test named `TestFoo(...)` and another `TestBar(...)`. `go test --run=TestFoo` will only run `TestFoo(...)`.

Comment: I try it and it doestn work , maybe becouse i use ginkgo ? does it beave diffrently ?

Comment: Ginkgo ties in to the testing framework, so that should be fine